# How to get jquery/javascript functions to fire once

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I am doing an json based multiple choice quiz. On click of the #next button, it fades out and brings in the submit button.button. I've noticed if i click twice quickly sometimes the count variable increments more than once and also the variable score which increments when the user is right . how can i get it to fire once, stop firing  then later make it clickable again. I was told about .off() jquery method but not sure how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/* report gives score after the last question=array length */
$('#next').on('mousedown',report);     

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    x++;  /* for selecting current question */
    count++;
    undo();  /* clears question area to load new one from json */
    placement();  /* brings in questions in json form */
    $(".alert").alert('close');  /* closes dialog */        

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's .one() method to fire an event once.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Ok .off() and .one() stops the function but how do re-enable the click so it does the function again?